# Why exactly does the calculus I doing work here?

Tags: integration, physics

The question is :- If $PQ$ is an infinite current-carrying conductor, and $AB$ and $CD$ are smooth conducting rods on which a conductor $EF$ moves with a constant velocity $V$. Find the force that needs to act on $EF$ to maintain a constant velocity,
A diagram :- [image]

I understand the physics, but I need help understanding the math.
the law that I used here is [Fraday's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction).

so $$-\frac{d\phi}{dt}=\frac{dBA}{dt}$$

and $B(x)$ = $\frac{\mu I}{2\pi x}$

where $B$ is the magnetic field

so the flux as an integral is written as
$$\int_a^b \frac{\mu I*l}{2\pi x} dx=\frac{\mu Il}{2\pi}\ln{\frac{b}{a}}$$
where $l$ is the instantaneous distance of $EF$ from pint $B$

from which we can then obtain the EMF as
$$d \frac{\frac{\mu Il}{2\pi}\ln{\frac{b}{a}}}{dt} = \frac{\mu Iv}{2\pi}\ln{\frac{b}{a}}$$

where $v$ is the velocity
This is what I did, and what my book did too, however, I have a problem with this method despite using it as I treated $l$ as a constant in one expression and as a variable in another.

What is the mathematically correct way to do this?

Credit for image:- Toppr.com

Comment: It seems like you can interpret $l$ as $l(t)$. If that's true, then it would make sense to pull $l$ out of the integral that's with respect to $x$. I'm not sure what "instantaneous distance" is, but if that means the position of an object at time $t$, then it makes sense to say $\frac{dl(t)}{dt} = v$ is the velocity.

Comment: yes, but that';s a variable, so how can I do that?

Comment: Do what exactly?

Comment: pull out the v from the integral

Comment: I don't see a $v$ being pulled out from the integral. Do you mean the $l$?

Comment: yes, Id o mean $l$

Comment: You can still pull out a variable from an integral as long as that variable doesn't depend on the variable the integral depends on. So yes, you can pull put the $l$ from the integral because it's not a function depending on $x$.